# Cannot find module 'normalize-package-data'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

When I am trying to install npm,
I'm getting this error.
[Description in Command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdqC8.png)

> Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 8.9.1 (x64) and
>   npm.
>
> D:\Project\angular\mCart>npm install npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
>   npm ERR! Cannot find module 'normalize-package-data'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\chaman.mandal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-11-22T0
>   5_18_52_300Z-debug.log

mCart is my project directory.
I am unable to find any solution related to normalize-package-data.
Is there anyway to install it manually?
Thanks.

Comment: try npm install npm@latest -g

Comment: Thanks it is working.